# Animation completed event raised before it is completely rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

How can I force an animation to wait its whole rendering before to keep going with my code?

I have a simple animation with shows a loading panel on a pretty heavy grid, I guess this takes some time to make the panel rendered with a fade in effect, unluckly completed event is raised before the animation is displayed and code keep going and start a data process that idles for few seconds (correctly) the application. This should be start after the panel is effectively rendered on screen!

Answer (score 0):

Is this animation done with the `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform`?

If `LayoutTransform` then I think in the animation completed event handle the `LayoutUpdated` event of the relevant visual. So probably when the visual actually first responds to the layout pass **after** the animation finishes, it will be the correct place for yourcode to start that new process. After the process starts unhook layoutupdated event for the same visual.

Sadly for `RenderTransform` there is no such event except `CompositionTarget.Rendering`. You can try handling this event explicitly in animation completed event. Also when rendering event is handled after the animation is completed, start your process and please unhook the rendering event. This event can make your application slow if it is left unhooked.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke an empty low prioratiy action:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

That blocks code execution until all actions with priority higher than `DispatcherPriority.Background` are processed. So you can ensure that your animation code has been processed before some other blocking code will be exeucted with higher priority( and the animation logic remains in the dispatcher queue).